# K0s: How to extend the default "service port range"?

Tags: kubernetes, port, k0s

I would like to extend the default "service port range" in [K0s Kubernetes distro](https://docs.k0sproject.io/v1.21.0+k0s.0/).

I know that in kubernetes, setting `--service-node-port-range` option in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` will do the trick.

But, how to do so or where is that option in the `K0s` distro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could use `spec.api.extraArgs` to pass the `service-node-port-range` parameter to api-server.

[Spec api](https://docs.k0sproject.io/v1.21.0+k0s.0/configuration/#specapi):

> **extraArgs**: Map of key-values (strings) for any extra arguments you wish to pass down to Kubernetes api-server process

Example:

```
apiVersion: k0s.k0sproject.io/v1beta1
kind: Cluster
metadata:
  name: k0s
spec:
  api:
    extraArgs:
      service-node-port-range: 30000-32767
```

Comment: Trying to apply this I get an error `no matches for kind "Cluster" in version "k0s.k0sproject.io/v1beta1"`

Comment: Made `k0s default-config >/etc/k0s.yaml`, `k0s stop`, `k0s reset`, `k0s install controller --config=/etc/k0s.yaml`, added that `extraArgs` to the config, then `k0s start` and it worked